# How do I solve a second order differential equation when y(t) is zero?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have something of the form:

my" + ky' = C

My problem here is when I try to take a particular solution and I choose yp = A, the equation becomes 0 = C when plugged in. How do I approach this? Is there no particular solution?

Comment: Try $y_p(x)=Ax$ instead.

Comment: because C is a constant.

Comment: @HansLundmark 
Thank you! That helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I would say - solve substitutions:

$my'' + ky' = C$, substitution y' = p, y'' = p',

so to solve linear equation $mp' + kp = C\Rightarrow p = c_1 e^{-(k t)/m}+C/k$,

the back substitution $y' = c_1 e^{-(k t)/m}+C/k\Rightarrow y=\int (c_1 e^{-(k t)/m}+C/k)dt + c_2$